# Проблема с созданием загрузочной флешки (Tails)

Tags: usb, bsod

Пытаюсь создать загрузочную USB: устанавливаю img образ Tails , при завершении загрузки крашится Windows 7. На выходе получаю BSoD(синий экран смерти), Винда говорит , что проблема с physical memory. После перезапуска комп видит флешку, но не открывает её. Форматировать получается только через Hard Disk Low Level Format Tool. Быть может кто сталкивался с данной проблемой? 
P.S. Для записи использую Etcher, также пробовал несколько других программок, результат тот же.

Comment: Интересные дела у вас творятся... лично я не сталкивался и где собака зарыта не знаю, но посоветовал бы вам во первых попробовать записать образ именно через UltraISO, а второе попробовать записать другой образ/на другую флешку, лишь методом проб и ошибок может быть станет ясно в чем проблема или где про это почитать...

Comment: Не подходит: UltraISO не работает с .img файлами.